# Можно ли писать простые приложения для Android на Python, не используя Kivy?

Tags: android, python, apk

Тратить огромное кол-во времени на изучение java для написания простеньких бот-программ считаю не лучшим решением.

Подскажите, можно ли писать приложения для android на python без использования kivy?

Comment: Но если вы знаете python, то почему не хотите использовать Kivy?

Comment: Есть проблема по установке Kvy

Comment: В вашем случае ответ нет. Нельзя писать без использования kivy

Comment: Можно. Не вводите людей в заблуждение.